# Why PageStack won't send property?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I have a basic code but it's impossible to send a property to an external page

This is my main.qml :

```
 PageStack {
        id: pageStack
        Component.onCompleted: push(pageMain)
        Page {
            title: i18n.tr("Main page")
            id:pageMain

            Button {
                objectName: "button"
                width: parent.width

                text: i18n.tr("send value")

                onClicked: {
                    var codeValue = "3029330003533";
                    console.log("code = " + codeValue);
                    pageStack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("qml/view.qml", {code: codeValue}));
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

And my qml/view.qml page

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import Ubuntu.Components 1.2

Page {
    title: "View"
    id: pageView
   property string code:"";

    Column {
        spacing: units.gu(1)
        anchors {
            margins: units.gu(2)
            fill: parent
        }

        Label {
            id: label
            objectName: "label"
            text: pageView.code
        }
    }
}
```

property "barcode" is always empty, where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You parens aren't quite right:

```
pageStack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("qml/view.qml"), {code: codeValue});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making your property name a string, like this: `{'code': codeValue}`, otherwise Qml is likely trying to evaluate *code* as a variable rather than a literal.

Comment: It's change nothing.
For test the values I had :  
  onCodeChanged: console.log(pageView.code) ;   -- but this method is never called --